# How to use beefe/react-native-keyboard in functional component?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, functional-programming, runtime-error

[Keyboard Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RziC4.png)

React native Numeric_keypad library required for numeric input only.
A another one is react-native-custom-keyboard but seems to not working in newer versions so this library is another one for the same task but without native implementation but no use case shown for the functional ones..

I tried adding all methods given for the same but with no output of working .it seems like model is not properly used as per functional context, so _notify does'nt exist error...

```
        </View> 
            <Keyboard 
                keyboardType="decimal-pad"
                onClear={this._handleClear.bind(this)}
                onDelete={this._handleDelete.bind(this)}
                onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress.bind(this)}
            />
        </View>
```

Link for the same is https://github.com/beefe/react-native-keyboard

```
 inputMode ={"decimal"}/keyboardType={"decimal-pad"} 
 requires secureTextEntry={true}
```

which treats number as passcode and also the ui flickers when navigate using Material Tob bar navigator having two tabs with `ref.focus()` both numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a package for this, it's included in the standard React Native library.  Use a TextInput with `keyboardType='numeric'`.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#keyboardtype

Comment: But it shows extra buttons for spaces/dashes etc..Also react-native-virtual-keyboard like library is good. but not many props to use onChangeText and Value..  Updated my question with keyboard image link..